# Compare values from one array with the values from 2nd array and based on that place the values from one array into 3rd array

Tags: powershell, loops, foreach, nested

I have these 2 arrays. Values in Array 1 are in the correct order. Values in the Array 2 are in incorrect order. What I need to do is loop through both array and sort the IPs so that the same IPs are in the same index in the array 2.

1. I was trying nested loops .
2. I was trying the nested loops below but no luck.
3. I have also tried nested ForEach but instead of getting the cross section, I get everything.
4. I have checked the compare-object cmdlet but it does not really seem useful in this case.
5. Any ideas?

$arrayOfItemsToCompare | ForEach-Object {
if ($array -contains $*) {
Write-Host $*
}
}

> ```
> Array 1:
>
> 192.168.3.1
> 192.168.1.1
> 10.49.50.254
> 0.0.0.0
> 90.183.197.126
> 194.228.115.69
> 90.182.79.231
> 90.182.78.193
> 194.228.115.67
> 194.228.115.66
> 194.228.190.115
> 194.228.92.85
> 172.253.50.253
> 108.170.238.231
> 216.58.201.68
>
> Array 2:
>
>
>
> DestinationIP   AverageLatency Success
>     -------------   -------------- -------
>     192.168.3.1                  0     100
>     192.168.1.1                  0     100
>     194.228.115.69            16.4     100
>     90.183.197.126              17     100
>     90.182.78.193             16.8     100
>     194.228.115.67            16.8     100
>     194.228.115.66            17.4     100
>     194.228.190.115           17.8     100
>     172.253.50.253            17.8     100
>     194.228.92.85             18.4     100
>     108.170.238.231             18     100
>     216.58.201.68             17.6     100
>     10.49.50.254                 0       0
>     90.182.79.231                0       0
> ```

Comment: Using this [`Join-Object script`](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/Join)/[`Join-Object Module`](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/JoinModule) (see also: [In Powershell, what's the best way to join two tables into one?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45483110/1701026)): `$Array1 |Join $Array2 -on Value -eq DestinationIP |Select-Object DestinationIP, AverageLatency, Success`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way you can sort your second **array of objects** based in the order of the first array could be by constructing an array of expressions.

Since this can be a bit hard to understand, let's use a simple example to understand this better. Given our example array `1, 2, 3` let's say we want to sort it in the order `3, 1, 2`. For that we can use multiple expressions with `Sort-Object`, the *expressions* are script blocks that will determine where a condition was `$true` and sort the result based on that order:

```
PS /> 1, 2, 3 | Sort-Object { $_ -eq 3 }, { $_ -eq 1 }, { $_ -eq 2 } -Descending

3
1
2
```

Using the same logic, here is how your second array can be sorted. Below assumes that **`$sortArray`** is the variable that contains the list of IPs and **`$arrayOfObjects`** is the variable containing the array of objects we need to sort based on the order of the first variable:

```
# ASSUMING THE ARRAY OF IPs is stored here
$sortArray = @(...)

# Store all the expressions in a variable
$expressions = foreach($i in $sortArray) {
    { $_.DestinationIP -eq $i }.GetNewClosure()
}

$arrayOfObjects | Sort-Object $expressions -Descending
```

Another alternative could be using `Group-Object -AsHashtable` to create a lookup table based on the **DestinationIP** values of `$arrayOfObjects` and then loop through the `$sortArray` to filter the objects:

```
$map = $arrayOfObjects | Group-Object DestinationIP -AsHashTable
foreach($obj in $sortArray) {
    if($value = $map[$obj]) {
        $value
    }
}
```

The output from both snippets should look like below:

```
DestinationIP   AverageLatency Success
-------------   -------------- -------
192.168.3.1     0              100
192.168.1.1     0              100
10.49.50.254    0              0
90.183.197.126  17             100
194.228.115.69  16.4           100
90.182.79.231   0              0
90.182.78.193   16.8           100
194.228.115.67  16.8           100
194.228.115.66  17.4           100
194.228.190.115 17.8           100
194.228.92.85   18.4           100
172.253.50.253  17.8           100
108.170.238.231 18             100
216.58.201.68   17.6           100
```